# How to make locally assigned clothes visible to all players?

Tags: lua, local, server-side, roblox

I have a local script that assigns shirts to players according to which team they are on. Here is the script:

view source

```
01  local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
02   
03  local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
04   
05  local shirt
06   
07  if player.Team == game.Teams["Red Team"] then
08  shirt = "http://www.roblox.com/asset?id=73022512"
09  elseif player.Team == game.Teams["Blue Team"] then
10  shirt =  "rbxassetid://184244692"
11  elseif player.Team == game.Teams["Yellow Team"] then
12  shirt = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=1210716332"
13  elseif player.Team == game.Teams["Green Team"] then
14  shirt = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=13997666"
15  end
16   
17  if char:FindFirstChild("Shirt") then
18  char.Shirt.ShirtTemplate = shirt
19  else
20  local newShirt = Instance.new("Shirt")
21  newShirt.Parent = char
22  newShirt.ShirtTemplate = shirt
23  end
```

This works. Problem is, other players can't see your shirt as it's only local. I can't paste this post on a server side script because - as far as I know - you can't access a character on a server side script. Am I right in assuming this? How would I make all shirts visible to all players? Thanks

Comment: A player's character can be found in the Workspace in a Model with the player's name. A server script can do this logic just fine. You just cannot access the player using game.Players.LocalPlayer, you'll need to find them in the Workspace instead.
`local char = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(thePlayerName)`

Answer (score 0):

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)    

    plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
          -- here check the player's team and change the shirt
    end)

end)
```

Try this way.